# no main manifest attribute, in jar while trying to create and run with console

Tags: java, swing, jar, attributeerror, manifest.mf

I'm trying to create a jar file with console and run it on windows.

Export.java

```
public class Export {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world :D");
    }
}
```

then I created the class file Running

```
C:\Users\inod.jayakody\eclipse-workspace\Program>javac Export.java
```

added the following manifest.mf file in the same folder containing

MANIFEST.MF

```
Main-Class: Export
```

created the jar file in cmd using

```
C:\Users\inod.jayakody\eclipse-workspace\Program>jar cmvf MANIFEST.MF Inod.jar *.class
added manifest
adding: Export.class(in = 524) (out= 336)(deflated 35%)
```

but when I'm running the file I'm getting following error am I doing anything wrong? what is the issue here?

```
C:\Users\inod.jayakody\eclipse-workspace\Program>java -jar Inod.jar
no main manifest attribute, in Inod.jar
```

Comment: You don't need manifests anymore for that: ```jar cvfe Inod.jar Export Export.class```. Then ```java -jar Inod.jar```

Comment: @g00sereciving this error   Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class Export
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Export has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 62.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 59.0

Comment: OK. That looks like you have different versions in PATH between java and javac. You need to harmonize them. ```java -version```  ```javac -version``` On Windows, I would set ```JAVA_HOME``` and then, place, *at the start* of ```PATH``` ```%JAVA_HOME%\bin;```

Comment: @g00se No I have the same versions: C:\Users\inod.jayakody\eclipse-workspace\Program>**java -version
java version "15.0.2"** 2021-01-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)

C:\Users\inod.jayakody\eclipse-workspace\Program>**javac -version
javac 15.0.2**

C:\Users\inod.jayakody\eclipse-workspace\Program>

Comment: Strange. You error message is telling you that class was compiled with Java 18. Delete the class file and try again (Obvs. recompile it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248315/discussion-between-g00se-and-inod-umayanga).